# Why $locationChangeSuccess event is fired multiply only with Chrome on iOS? And eventually fail to change location

Tags: ios, angularjs, google-chrome

I write my application with angularjs.

I've faced the strange problem.
As I wrote as title, $locationChangeSuccess event is fired multiply **ONLY** with Chrome on iOS (About more than 10 times).

This is my code.
If you save this code to some html file, you can run it locally. But when you try this code on iOS device, you need some server(I use nodejs).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<body>

    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <h2>Links</h2>
        <div>
            <a href="#/page1">Page1</a>
            <a href="#/page2">Page2</a>
        </div>

        <h2>URL History</h2>
        <div>
            <a href ng-click="clearhistory()">Clear History</a>
            <div ng-repeat="url in urlhistory track by $index">
                {{url}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

(function(){
    angular.module('myapp', ['ngCookies'])
        .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $location, $cookies) {
            $scope.urlhistory = [];

            $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event, newurl, prevurl) {
                $scope.urlhistory.push(newurl);
                // If I comment out this line, url changes correctly. But $locationChangeSuccess event is still fired multiple.
                $cookies.somevalue = $location.path();
            });

            $scope.clearhistory = function(){
                $scope.urlhistory = [];
            };
        })
        ;
})();

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click the link to page1 on chrome of PC, I got the message like below on the page.

```
URL History
http://localhost:3000/
http://localhost:3000/#/page1
```

And success to change location actualy.
This is what I expected. There are no problems.

But When I do this on my iPadmini-chrome and iPhone-chrome, I got the message like below.

```
URL History
http://localhost:3000/
http://localhost:3000/#/page1
http://localhost:3000/#/page1
http://localhost:3000/#/page1
http://localhost:3000/#/page1
http://localhost:3000/#/page1
http://localhost:3000/#/page1
http://localhost:3000/#/page1
http://localhost:3000/#/page1
http://localhost:3000/#/page1
http://localhost:3000/#/page1
http://localhost:3000/#/page1
http://localhost:3000/
```

Somehow I got 11 same messages and eventually fail to change location.
When I do this on safari of the same iPadmini, I got the same messages as chrome on PC.
My iPadmini-chrome version is 46.0.2490.73. I'm suspicious of the new version chrome because there was no problem a few months ago.

## There are two questions I want to know.

1. Why does Chrome on ipadmini fire $locationChangeSuccess events multiply(11 times!)?
2. As you can see the last line of messages on ipadmini-chrome, eventualy I can't move to page1 even though I click the link to page1.
   Is there some solution for this real problem?

I will appreciate any suggestion. Thanks!